# MD5 Hash Value before Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, md5

I have a field in an `Order` table that gets populated by other values which works fine as per example below:

```
company_name: A-Z Traders
company_tel: (111) 111 1111
MD5_hash_field: A-Z Traders|(011) 111 1111
```

This is working on the creation of the record through hidden field.

What I require is that `MD5_hash_field` then gets MD5 hashed before it is saved into the database.

Tried adding the following:

```
before_create :hash_field

def hash_field
  self.md5_field = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.md5_field)
end
```

But does not seem to do anything

Edit:

It does Work to a Degree

```
<%= f.hidden_field :checksum, :value => '10011013800|Customer1|3299|ZAR|http://localhost|2012-01-30 18:30:00|secret' %> 

   Result should be: 31d1244f08a62f0551e9263c4835ba88

   but getting : aae1ee590e4d4e08e7c0363cca90a22b
```

Solved:

```
This Does Work! - Fellow Developers when working on multiple Applications make sure you are restarting the correct App. LOL
```

Comment: Can you add a sample record which demonstrates 'before' and 'after' states?

Comment: Ok Managed to get it to work to a degree was doing something stupid on my part, but the result i am getting is wrong

Comment: Edited the Question, any idea why the result is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you change the code to

```
def hash_field
  p self.md5_field
  self.md5_field = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.md5_field)
end
```

And see what it gives you in the logs?